# After deleting a comment, most buttons won't work until you refresh the page

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments, microsoft-edge

After deleting a comment while using Microsoft Edge browser, none of the action buttons will work (up/down vote, close, flag, etc.) until you refresh the page. I faced this in Travel.SE but I assume it's an SE wide issue.

I have tested this with Chrome/IE11 and I do not see the same behavior. I am using Windows 10 with November update.

Note: sometimes it just does not happen, most of the times it does.

### Update

It's been 10 days with no reply from any SE team member, does that mean the bug does not exist or does it mean it's not a priority?

Comment: I couldn't repro in Safari 9.0.2, guess it's only the Edgebug.

Comment: Pity upvote just because you're using IE. Sorry, Edge.

Comment: @ShadowWizard [LOL, You reminded me of this!](http://i.imgur.com/fuaz2ZZ.jpg)

Comment: LOL, still wiping my eyes from the tears.... good one! :-D

Comment: I can reproduce this using IE 10 on Windows 7. The same thing happens sometimes after editing a comment.

Comment: Regarding your edit: this is not a critical bug. You can still use the site. Hence it's somewhere down the (very long) list of bugs. No worry, at some point they will probably take a look, but that point can take, well, 6-8 weeks.

Comment: Also, regarding the edit: there's also a lot of holiday etc that happens at the end of December...

Comment: @MarcGravell wow. Nice to know.

Answer (score 1):

We haven't been able to reproduce this bug. If you have a better repro I can take a look later this week.